# CheckYerFlags: Notifying when a user reaches a certain flag amount

Tags: app, api-v2.2, flags

### About CheckYerFlags

This bots notifies users when they reach an amount of certain flags (so called [flag ranks](https://github.com/SOBotics/FlaggersHall/issues/11)), for example 1,111 or 33,333 in a chat room and also provides them a command to get the current amount of their helpful flags. Chat users can also specify a custom rank.

#### Commands

You can get a list of all commands in chat by calling it like this `@CheckYerFlags commands`. In order to work, the bot must be in a chat room where the bot runs, obviously.

#### License & Download

CheckYerFlags is licensed under the [MIT license](https://github.com/SOBotics/FlaggersHall/blob/master/LICENSE).

To download a stable version, jump directly [to the releases](https://github.com/SOBotics/FlaggersHall/releases), for the code, visit the repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/SOBotics/FlaggersHall).

The bot runs in [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics), if you want to check your flag rank without installing or running something by yourself.

#### Platform

The bot should work on every system that runs Python 3, but it was only tested on those operating systems:

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (server)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (both desktop and server)

### Contact

If you have a question about this bot, feel free to ping me in [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics).

### Code

**Used programming language and libraries:** Python 3 and ChatOverflow, a fork of ChatExchange by ManishEarth (Which is a python library for interacting with the chat).

Comment: Would you add the list of commands to the read.me as well? Thanks.

Comment: @M-- I just saw that this post ist due some edits anyway, and a proper command in this post was planned for some time. I'll see that I can find some time to tend to this.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. The bot has been down for the past week though; I thought you're just giving up on it :(